# jquery css3 gradient plugin

Tags: jquery, css, gradient

Does anyone know of a jquery css3 plugin that supports cross browser gradients. All the gradient plugins I've seen thus far are based on creating many elements.

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry for being unclear, I'm not trying to make CSS3 work on browsers that don't support it. I know I can use gradients on the browsers that support CSS3 gradients, and using IE filters. I'm trying to see if anyone has already written a jQuery plugin so that I can do it in the code.

for instance jquery core standardizes `elem.css('opacity', '.5')` so that it works cross browsers regardless of the different syntaxes. Looking for something like this for gradients too.

But if it doesn't exist I guess I'll just write it myself.

Comment: CSS3 supports gradients, you don't need jQuery plugin for that. The problem is that not all browsers implement CSS3.

Comment: @RaYell, I want to do something like: `elem.css(gradient(#000).to(#fff));` in js without having to manually write out all the CSS by hand, which is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today you use cssHooks to do jquery gradients cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Mmmmm, pie.`**](http://css3pie.com/)

```
CSS3PIE - Progressive Internet Explorer - makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable
of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.
```

This `.htc` is really easy to implement and use.

Answer (score 0):

creating a lot of elements is the only way to get a cross-browser gradient when you don't want to use an image - and jquery can't create images dynamically. use one of those (bad ?) plugins or simply use photoshop (or gimp (or paint)) to create your gradient.

my favourite is: support gradients for nice, modern browsers (new safari / firefox versions, internet explorer) and use a normal background-color as fallback for the bad browsers (old safari / firefox versions)

**NOTE:** in this case, IE is one of the good browsers, it [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx) gradients since... all the time i can remember

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically jQuery, but using Raphael (javascript graphics library) you can set cross browser gradients. See settings under http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#attr.

Note: this is a vector graphics library implementation that uses various technologies depending on the browser to achieve its effects.

Answer (score 0):

The only cross-browser way to create a gradient is to create elements with changing background colors. Support for moz, webkit and IE browsers are possible, with 3 rules(every gradient):

```
/* IE */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#ffffff00,endColorstr=#00000000);
/* webkit(Safari, Chrome) */
-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,right bottom,color-stop(1, rgb(0,0,0)),color-stop(0, rgb(255,255,255)));
/* mozilla(Firefox) */
-moz-linear-gradient(left center,rgb(0,0,0) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 0%);
```

Then you could have a fallback with a normal background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you find coding CSS3 gradients difficult, you can try CSS3 gradient generators. You can find a list of gradients [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633281/how-to-make-exact-css3-linear-gradient-like-its-in-the-image/9146127#9146127).